# ArcGIS SelectLayerByAttribute is not working

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I have the following script:

```
Area_f = input_folder + "\\Area_f.shp"
Area_f_layer = "Area_f_layer"

fld_objekt_nr = "OBJEKT_NR"

arcpy.AddField_management(Area_f_layer, fld_objekt_nr, flt_double, "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Area_f_layer, "NEW_SELECTION", "\'ALPHA\' = '0'")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Area_f_layer, fld_objekt_nr, "12345", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

`"ALPHA"` is a string filled with NULL and 1. `"OBJEKT_NR"` is a double.

I would like `OBJEKT_NR` to be `12345` in all rows that have `ALPHA=NULL`, instead I get `OBJEKT_NR=12345` in every row.
I'm not sure if this is a syntax problem or my data is anyhow corrupt. Or is my code completely wrong?

I tried different syntax options like `'ALPHA' = '0'` or `"ALPHA" = '0'`, or `'\'ALPHA\' = \'0\'` that I found in other Q&As, but nothing worked.

Comment: This workflow is a good example of why you should always test if a selection exists, you cannot assume that a selection always works. I would put into your logic a test to see if selection > 0, you can do that with the GetCount tool. Look at the script examples in the help file for this tool.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I added the Counter, which makes it a lot easier to check if the selection works.

Comment: If you want to process records with `ALPHA=NULL`, why do you query for `ALPHA='0'`?

Comment: As noted by @Berend if you want to select null value you should try something like "ALPHA IS NULL"' rather than "ALPHA = 0" Also if ALPHA is a text string you may also try testing for empty string

Answer (score 1):

If ALPHA is a numeric field then I think you should try:

```
"ALPHA = 0"
```

If it’s a text field then try:

```
"ALPHA = '0'"
```

Comment: thank you very much. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I added the GetCount that Hornbydd suggested, but your attempt gives me back a "0". Maybe there is another mistake in my code.

Comment: Note that the code in this answer has 'curly quotes' instead of straight quotes, so if you copy-paste this, it won't work. If ALPHA is indeed a text field, it should be `ALPHA='0'`. Or, as in the original code: `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Area_f_layer, "NEW_SELECTION", "ALPHA = '0'")`